# Routing acording to xml nodename

Tags: jboss

```js
<Body>
  <ProductMasterDataStatus>
    <Status>INVALID</Status>
    <Errors>
      <Error source="HUB">
        <Description>Data Validation Error (Product code length is invalid.)</Description>
        <Code>#A16</Code>
      </Error>
    </Errors>
  </ProductMasterDataStatus>
</Body>
```

> I want to check the ProductMasterDataStatus is in this xml if it is there i want to change the route in camel route.

```js
 <camelContext id="cbr-example-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="_route1">
            <from id="_from1" uri="file:///d:/in"/>
            
            <camel:choice id="_choice1">
                <camel:when id="_when1">
                    <camel:xpath>
                           
                        </camel:xpath>
                    <camel:to id="_to1" uri="file:C:/outbox_Denmark"/>
                </camel:when>
            
            
            <process id="_process_transform" ref="myTransform"/>
            <to id="_to1" uri="file:///d:/out?fileName=Product.xml"/>
        </route>
```

Comment: Hello @Sameera Athukorala, did you see my proposal? Does it fits you?

Comment: i want to check the NodeName here,this one  ProductMasterDataStatus not its value

Comment: I thought initially you said about "Status", anyway you can write //ProductMasterDataStatus instead. I will change my answer too. Is this ok? It is working?

Comment: i want to check this tag ProductMasterDataStatus is included in this xml or not is this way possible to do that ?

Comment: did you see my answer? //ProductMasterDataStatus != null Is this works for you, did you try it?

Comment: ok il try thank you

Answer (score 0):

The xpath expression is **//ProductMasterDataStatus**, so you should check if this is not null.

```
<camelContext id="cbr-example-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="_route1">
            <from id="_from1" uri="file:///d:/in"/>

            <camel:choice id="_choice1">
                <camel:when id="_when1">
                    <camel:xpath>//ProductMasterDataStatus != null</camel:xpath>
                    <camel:to id="_to1" uri="file:C:/outbox_Denmark"/>
                </camel:when>


            <process id="_process_transform" ref="myTransform"/>
            <to id="_to1" uri="file:///d:/out?fileName=Product.xml"/>
        </route>
```